# kml multiple pushpins, cursor solution in data base

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kml

I am new to programming, (just 2 months)

I am writing an app that logs your latitude and longitude as you drive around and pick weeds. It then creates a kml file so that you (the farmer) can see where you have been.

If you pick four weeds on the same spot (same lat and long) the output is a single kml pushpin, which when you click on it expands into four; however, this means that the farmer has to click on all of the pins to see the multiple ones.

Here is my the code that makes my kml

```
      db = openOrCreateDatabase(rabbitsrv.DATABASE_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
               cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * " +
            " FROM " + rabbitsrv.BAG_TABLE_NAME +
            " ORDER BY LATITUDE ASC;",
            null);
    int gmtTimestampColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("GMTTIMESTAMP");
    int latitudeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("LATITUDE");
    int longitudeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("LONGITUDE");  
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        StringBuffer fileBuf = new StringBuffer();
                        String beginTimestamp = null;
                        String endTimestamp = null;
                        String gmtTimestamp = null;
                        initFileBufk(fileBuf, initValuesMap());
                        do {gmtTimestamp = cursor.getString(gmtTimestampColumnIndex);
                        if (beginTimestamp == null) {beginTimestamp = gmtTimestamp;}
                                double latitude = cursor.getDouble(latitudeColumnIndex);
                                double longitude = cursor.getDouble(longitudeColumnIndex);
                                fileBuf.append("<Placemark><Point><coordinates>"+
                                        sevenSigDigits.format(longitude)+","+sevenSigDigits.format(latitude)+
                                                "</coordinates></Point></Placemark>\n");
                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        endTimestamp = gmtTimestamp;
                        cursor.moveToLast();
                        closeFileBufk(fileBuf, beginTimestamp, endTimestamp);
                        String fileContents = fileBuf.toString();
                        Log.d(tag, fileContents);
```

What I really want to do is have an if statement. I know the below doesn't work as I made up `.nextvalue`:

```
if ((cursor.lat==cursor.nextvalue.lat)&(cursor.long==cursor.nextvalue,long){
    // make purple pushpin
} else {
    // make yellow pushpin.
}
```

Even better would be if I could count how many weeds I had at the same lat and long, and if there were 7 (for example) I could make a flag with number 7 on it.

The kml side of it I can do - it is the sql/cursor bit I am stuck with.